# Is there a way to use SET MARKUP CSV on in the Command window in PL/SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, plsqldeveloper, spool

My code currently that I am running in the Command Window in PL/SQL Developer:

```
SET MARKUP CSV ON DELIMITER | QUOTE OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF

SPOOL C:\Users\Desktop\SpoolTest.csv

select *
from Vendor_data t 
where rownum < 20
;

SPOOL OFF;
```

My output:

```
222339           |067   |001 

306811           |045   |001 

024253           |067   |001
```

I need to remove the trailing spaces:

```
222339|067|001 

306811|045|001
 
024253|067|001
```

I am getting Cannot SET MARKUP.  I have to run my spooling in a  command window in PL/SQL Developer.  Is there a way to do this?  This is a snippet of code which is actually quite long.

Answer (score 1):

The PL/SQL Developer's command-line tool is a different product than Oracle `SQL*Plus` command-line utility, and it has a different set of supported commands.  PL/SQL Developer's command line mimics a real SQL*Plus functionality but does it only partially. For example, it doesn't support the `SET MARKUP CSV` command. You can find the full list of supported commands in the PL/SQL Developer's Manual (Help -> User's Guide).

In your case, trailing spaces appear because you are printing headers of columns. Apparently, PL/SQL Developer tries to align rows by the maximum length of the column:

```
spool file.txt

select ao.object_name, ao.object_id, ao.created, ao.status
  from all_objects ao
 where rownum <= 3;

OBJECT_NAME                                                                       OBJECT_ID CREATED     STATUS
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- ----------- -------
TS$                                                                                      16 26.01.2017  VALID
ICOL$                                                                                    20 26.01.2017  VALID
```

Keeping in mind that PL/SQL Developer's supports of SET commands is very limited, we can achieve the CSV like spooling by simply not printing headers and setting colwidth to 1:

```
spool file.txt

set colsep |
set heading off
set colwidth 1

select ao.object_name, ao.object_id, ao.created, ao.status
  from all_objects ao
 where rownum <= 3;

spool off
```

it saves this to the spool file:

```
TS$|16|26.01.2017 13:52:45|VALID
ICOL$|20|26.01.2017 13:52:45|VALID
C_FILE#_BLOCK#|8|26.01.2017 13:52:45|VALID
```

If you must print the headers, you can add an additional select from dual before the main sql just to print headers.

Answer (score 0):

`SET` commands belong to Oracle's command line tool, SQL*Plus.

I don't use PL/SQL Developer (and quick Google doesn't return anything useful), so - does PL/SQL Developer support `SET` commands at all? If not, you're out of luck, but you could install Oracle Client (if you already don't have it) and run your script directly in SQL*Plus.

On the other hand & unless I'm wrong, `SET MARKUP CSV` is valid for Oracle 18c and above; in lower versions, it is `SET MARKUP HTML` you can use (i.e. no `CSV` option).